# pandas dataframe: duplicates based on column and time range

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, duplicates, conditional-statements

I have a (very simplyfied here) pandas dataframe which looks like this:

`df`

```
    datetime             user   type   msg
0  2012-11-11 15:41:08   u1     txt    hello world
1  2012-11-11 15:41:11   u2     txt    hello world
2  2012-11-21 17:00:08   u3     txt    hello world
3  2012-11-22 18:08:35   u4     txt      hello you
4  2012-11-22 18:08:37   u5     txt      hello you
```

What I would like to do now is to get all the **duplicate messages which have their timestamp within 3 seconds**. The desired output would be:

```
   datetime              user   type   msg
0  2012-11-11 15:41:08   u1     txt    hello world
1  2012-11-11 15:41:11   u2     txt    hello world
3  2012-11-22 18:08:35   u4     txt      hello you
4  2012-11-22 18:08:37   u5     txt      hello you
```

without the third row, as its text is the same as in row one and two, but its timestamp is not
within the range of 3 seconds.

I tried to define the columns datetime and msg as parameters for the `duplicate()` method, but it returns an empty dataframe because the timestamps are not identical:

```
mask = df.duplicated(subset=['datetime', 'msg'], keep=False)

print(df[mask])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [datetime, user, type, msg, MD5]
Index: []
```

Is there a way where I can define a range for my "datetime" parameter? To illustrate, something
like:

```
mask = df.duplicated(subset=['datetime_between_3_seconds', 'msg'], keep=False)
```

Any help here would as always be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

This Piece of code gives the expected output

```
df[(df.groupby(["msg"], as_index=False)["datetime"].diff().fillna(0).dt.seconds <= 3).reset_index(drop=True)]
```

I have grouped on "msg" column of dataframe and then selected "datetime" column of that dataframe and used inbuilt function [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html). Diff function finds the difference between values of that column. Filled the NaT values with zero and selected only those indexes which have values less than 3 seconds.

Before using above code make sure that your dataframe is sorted on datetime in ascending order.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, don't forget accept it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, accepted, thank you very much for your help (and sorry for the delay)! It does what I needed.

Comment: @dliv thanks for up voting the answer. Glad I could help you. Please check this link to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) answer.

Comment: The ```fillna(0)``` needs to be replaced with ```fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0))``` now.

Answer (score 1):

This bit of code works on your example data, although you might have to play around with any extreme cases.

From your question I'm assuming you want to filter out messages from the first time it appears in df. It won't work if you have instances where you want to keep the string if it appears again after another threshold.

In short I wrote a function that will take your dataframe and the 'msg' to filter for. It takes the timestamp of the first time the message appears and compares that to all the other times it appears.

It then selects only the instances where it appears within 3 seconds of the first appearance.

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    #function which will return dataframe containing messages within three seconds of the first message
    def get_info_within_3seconds(df, msg):
        df_of_msg = df[df['msg']==msg].sort_values(by = 'datetime')
        t1 = df_of_msg['datetime'].reset_index(drop = True)[0]
        datetime_deltas = [(i -t1).total_seconds() for i in df_of_msg['datetime']]
        filter_list = [i <= 3.0 for i in datetime_deltas]
        return df_of_msg[filter_list]

    msgs = df['msg'].unique()
    #apply function to each unique message and then create a new df 
    new_df = pd.concat([get_info_within_3seconds(df, i) for i in msgs])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Tkanno! Your suggestion was helpful as well!