# duplicates by timestamp difference pandas not working

Tags: python, pandas

I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777114/pandas-dataframe-duplicates-based-on-column-and-time-range) . I need to get all rows where within one second the next row has the same price. So it's same problem as the other question but it isn't working for me.

I'm using python 3.6.3 and pandas version 0.22.0

my df:

```
                    timestamp   price
    0  2018-04-29 13:14:43.026  6394.0
    1  2018-04-29 13:16:53.714  6378.0
    2  2018-04-29 13:17:01.324  6378.0
    3  2018-04-29 13:17:02.246  6384.0
    4  2018-04-29 13:17:07.413  6384.0
    5  2018-04-29 13:17:08.331  6380.0
    6  2018-04-29 13:17:11.437  6380.0
    7  2018-04-29 13:17:11.895  6377.0
    8  2018-04-29 13:17:13.449  6377.0
    9  2018-04-29 13:17:13.452  6379.0

    timestamp    datetime64[ns]
    price               float64
    dtype: object
```

I try the following code:

```
 data = df[(df.groupby(["price"], as_index=False)["timestamp"].diff().fillna(0).dt.seconds <= 1).reset_index(drop=True)]
```

and this is the result:

```
                    timestamp   price
    0 2018-04-29 13:14:43.026  6394.0
    1 2018-04-29 13:16:53.714  6378.0
    2 2018-04-29 13:17:01.324  6378.0
    4 2018-04-29 13:17:07.413  6384.0
    5 2018-04-29 13:17:08.331  6380.0
    7 2018-04-29 13:17:11.895  6377.0
    9 2018-04-29 13:17:13.452  6379.0
```

EDIT:

The output should be empty but if we make this dataframe i.e.

```
                    timestamp   price
    0  2018-04-29 13:14:43.026  6394.0
    1  2018-04-29 13:16:53.714  6378.0
    2  2018-04-29 13:17:01.324  6378.0
    3  2018-04-29 13:17:02.246  6378.0
    4  2018-04-29 13:17:07.413  6384.0
    5  2018-04-29 13:17:08.331  6380.0
    6  2018-04-29 13:17:11.437  6380.0
    7  2018-04-29 13:17:11.895  6377.0
    8  2018-04-29 13:17:13.449  6377.0
    9  2018-04-29 13:17:13.452  6377.0
```

it should output:

```
                    timestamp   price

    2  2018-04-29 13:17:01.324  6378.0
    3  2018-04-29 13:17:02.246  6378.0
    8  2018-04-29 13:17:13.449  6377.0
    9  2018-04-29 13:17:13.452  6377.0
```

Comment: The issue is with your `.fillna(0)`. You're filling with 0, which then means every single one of those show up in your logic for  `< 0`. Fill with some other value, like 999

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @ALollz it should only be for the first value since all have a timestamp. So shouldn't really matter.

Comment: @user3605780 Since your grouping first, and then performing a `.diff()` you get far more `NaN` values than you think you are getting. Within EVERY group, the first row is `NaN` for the diff, not just the first row of your 10 row `df`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I added extra example data

Comment: @ALollz, ah yes indeed you are correct in this point, however I tried it and it does filter the first values for each price but it still isn't returning the correct output. So the error should be somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, I think you're over complicating this a bit, you should just need to take the diff:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(
'''timestamp                price
2018-04-29 13:14:43.026  6394.0
2018-04-29 13:16:53.714  6378.0
2018-04-29 13:17:01.324  6378.0
2018-04-29 13:17:02.246  6378.0
2018-04-29 13:17:07.413  6384.0
2018-04-29 13:17:08.331  6380.0
2018-04-29 13:17:11.437  6380.0
2018-04-29 13:17:11.895  6377.0
2018-04-29 13:17:13.449  6377.0
2018-04-29 13:17:13.452  6379.0'''
), colspecs=[(0,23), (25, 31)], dtype={
    'timestamp': 'datetime64[ns]',
    'price': 'float'
})


diff = df.diff()
selection = (diff['timestamp'].dt.seconds <=1) & (diff['price'] == 0)
selection = selection | selection.shift(periods=-1)
print(df[selection])
```

Output

```
                timestamp   price
2 2018-04-29 13:17:01.324  6378.0
3 2018-04-29 13:17:02.246  6378.0
7 2018-04-29 13:17:11.895  6377.0
8 2018-04-29 13:17:13.449  6377.0
```

Comment: @user3605780 Sorry, spaced out for a second there, I meant to shift in the other direction, it should now have the correct output.